# I cannot configure the Emulator Manager(Base Image) in Tizen

Tags: image, emulation, tizen

When I create the vm in Emulator Manager(Tizen) there I did not found Base Image. It shows to open the Browse folder to find the base image. But I don't know where from I can collect the Base Image.

Please let me know the PATH I can Browse it.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening your Install Manager to make sure you have installed the platform image associated with the emulator. It is located in Configure->Platforms->Tizen 2.2->Platform Image.

The image itself is located in: /tizen-sdk/platforms/tizen2.2/emulator-images/default/x86-standard$

Answer (score 0):

Where you install your tizen SDK like
C:\tizen-sdk\platforms\tizen2.2\emulator-images\default\x86-standard